# How to measure the position of an element in web page using selenium RC?

Tags: automation, selenium-rc, autoit, browser-automation, watij

I have tried a lot in finding out how measure the coordinate of an element in a web page in different browser.But I could not find any solution.

Is there any other tool that can measure the position of an element in various browsers???

Comment: Do you mean that for n browsers you are expecting the width to change?

Answer (score 1):

In AutoIt you can use the following code to get screen coordinates (in my example for displaying a tool tip as an overlay on an Internet Explorer):

```
$oIE = _IECreate("http://...URL...")
$username = _IEFormElementGetObjByName(_IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "loginform"), "username")
ToolTip("Login", _IEPropertyGet($username, "screenx"), _IEPropertyGet($username, "screeny"))
_IEAction($username, "focus")
```

Alternatively you can use `_IEGetObjById($oIE, "mx77")` to get an object reference. Or run through all all elemnts by tag name as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417940/autoit-ieformelementradioselect-without-finding-form).
Instead of getting the absolute screen position, you can get the In-Browser-Position, using
`browserx` and `browsery`.