# How to use _IEFormElementRadioSelect without finding a Form

Tags: automation, autoit

I need this script to work, but without using `_IEFormGetObjByName` or `_IEFormGetCollection`, and while knowing only the `Name` of the radio buttons.

```
$oIE = _IE_Example ("form")
$oDoc = _IEDocGetObj($oIE)
$oArray = $oDoc.getElementsByTagName ("input")
For $element In $oArray
If $element.Name = "radioExample" Then

_IEFormElementRadioSelect ($oDoc,2, "radioExample", 1, "byIndex")
msgbox(0,"","Found it")
Endif
Next
```

`_IEFormElementGetValue` & `_IEAction` work great, just reference them to the `$oElement`, and search for an appropriate `$element.Name`, but I can't get the _IEFormElementRadioSelect to work.

The only difference between the `_IEFormElementRadioSelect` command from the example script found in the AutoIt helpfile is the reference to `$oDoc`. In the helpfile this is `$oForm`, which is found with a `_IEFormGetObjByName`, which I can't use (the site I'm automating doesn't return any forms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `_IEFormElementRadioSelect` with `_IEAction($element, "click")`

Try this example; you can see the radio items being selected as the script runs:

```
#include <IE.au3>

$oIE = _IE_Example("form")
$oDoc = _IEDocGetObj($oIE)
$oArray = $oDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
For $element In $oArray
    If $element.Name = "radioExample" Then
        _IEAction($element, "click")
        Sleep(2000)
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now I can get back to work on the main script I was building!! If I had 15 rep, I'd vote your awnser up, but unfortunately I don't

Comment: No problem, Thomas. We get rep for just answering a question as well. :) Marking as answered is all I ever wanted.